# concatenate URL in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I was looking to concatenate URL based on keyword given. I passed a variable called "udefine" however, I'm not able to execute the complete concatenated URL. Code provided below.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str1="http://myuti.eit.go2uti.com/owd/ITII/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k="
set str2=%udefine%
set str3="^&cs=This%%20Site^&u=http%%3A%%2F%%2Fmyuti.eit.go2uti.com%%2Fowd%%2FITII"
set newvar =!%str1%%str2%%str3%!
echo %newvar%
```

I'm looking to concatenate str1, str2 and str3 as single URL based on input value to str2, the URL should change.

Comment: Thanks Steve Fonton for the edit !! :)

Answer (score 1):

The command `set var =x` differs from the `set var=x`. In the first case you setup the `[var ]` variable, in the second - `[var]`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "udefine=___"
set "str1=http://myuti.eit.go2uti.com/owd/ITII/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k="
set str2=%udefine%
set "str3=&cs=This%%20Site&u=http%%3A%%2F%%2Fmyuti.eit.go2uti.com%%2Fowd%%2FITII"
set "newvar=%str1%%str2%%str3%
echo "%newvar%"
endlocal
```

Output:

```
"http://myuti.eit.go2uti.com/owd/ITII/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx?k=___&cs=This%20Site&u=http%3A%2F%2Fmyuti.eit.go2uti.com%2Fowd%2FITII"
```

You can use `set /p str2=Enter udefine:` to input a value of `str2` from command prompt.

Comment: This worked for me. As suggested, please post your output. Remove the `@echo off` to see what commands are actually being run.